# Is "literally" similar to "almost", and is "technically" similar to "hardly"?

Tags: word-choice

Merriam Webster says:

> **Literally:** in effect : VIRTUALLY —used in an exaggerated way to emphasize a statement or description that is not literally true or possible.
>
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally)

Google says

> used for emphasis or to express strong feeling while not being literally true.
> "I was literally blown away by the response I got"

May I say that "literally" is similar to *almost*?

According to Vocabulary:

> **Technically** Something technically true is actually, really true or correct but it may not be the way people think about it. For example, although people call a tomato a vegetable, technically it's a fruit.
>
> [[Vocabulary]](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/technically)

Is "technically" similar to *hardly*?

Thanks.

Comment: There's two questions here.

Answer (score 3):

No. *Technically*, in the contexts of this kind, means *in accordance with the technical terminology of the relevant field*, as opposed to the casual, everyday usage. A tomato is a fruit if one uses the word *fruit* in accordance with the terminology of botany, but it would be a wrong thing to say in casual conversation, because the everyday sense of the word is different (it is limited to what is typically eaten in desserts). One can express that by saying that, technically, a tomato is a fruit.

A botanist would not say that a tomato is hardly a fruit: if one uses the word *fruit* in the technical sense that it has in botany, then a tomato is most definitely a fruit. On the other hand, if one uses the word *fruit* in the everyday sense, then a tomato just isn't a fruit. If you tell somebody 'Please bring me some fruit from the larder', and the person came back with tomatoes, that would be a mistake.

(This answer does not address *literally*, because a search for that word on this site will readily lead to a number of pages on which the matter is addressed extensively.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes to the first.

"Literally" in this sense means "Virtually", " Almost"-- so you could use the words interchangeably without a significant shift in meaning.

NO to the second.

In fact, you are suggesting just the opposite. In other words, "tomato is technically a fruit" means strictly speaking, it is a fruit and not a vegetable-- that is, botanically speaking, it satisfies the criteria of a fruit more than it does of a vegetable. But since it is more often cooked or taken as a vegetable, it isn't called a fruit.

Comment: In one respect, I hate the fact that one sense of *literally* is now defined as *not literally true*. In short, the definition itself says that the word doesn't mean what the word means. (Even discounting the word being used in the definition itself; in this case, it's referring to a different sense of the word.)

Comment: I would say that the misuse of "literally" is that it replaces its opposite "figuratively" not "almost" or "vritually". "Virtually" is misused to mean "almost" but "literally" is misused to mean "figuratively". For example in the OP's example "I was literally blown away" there is no suggestion that the speaker is, in fact (that is _literally_), blown away by a gust of wind or an explosion. The speaker is using "blown away" as a metaphor so is speaking figuratively.